# Were there fruit fly or silkworm eggs in the biosphere of the Chang'e 4 lander?

Tags: the-moon, chang-e

Drosophila melanogaster or bombyx mori?

```
29 700 google hits for chang'e silkworm
27 500 chang'e drosophila
25 100 chang'e "fruit fly"
```

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang%E2%80%99e-4 says silkworms.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang'e_4 said fruit fly before I changed it to "fruit fly or silkmoth".

Any reliable sources?

Comment: whatever they were, they're dead now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They were fruit flies, according to a [Chongqing University web page](http://english.cqu.edu.cn/info/1038/1941.htm) (the page claims CQU was the lead in that experiment)

Earlier stories talked about silkworms; it's possible these were changed to fruit flies as plans progressed: fruit flies can consume ethanol, which yeast (also added in later reports) can produce while breaking down organic mater.